# Using a4j:repeat or ui:repeat inside rich:dataTable doesn't render radio buttons properly

Tags: jsf, seam, richfaces, jstl

While using `<c:forEach>` the items values is not substituted properly. If i use `<a4j:repeat>` or `<ui:repeat>` instead of `<c:forEach>` inside a `<rich:dataTable`>, radio button is not rendering properly. I also found reason for this in http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Cantusea4jrepeattoiteratethemenuItemstabsetc

How do I resolve this issue?

`<f:selectItems>` is working inside  but i want to send a choice type to server

```
  <rich:dataTable var="answer" value="#{answers}">
    <rich:column>
      <f:selectOneRadio value="#{response.value}">
        <c:forEach items="#{answer.choices}" var="choice">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{choice.value}" itemValue="#{choice.type}"/>
        </c:forEach>
     </f:selectOneRadio>
   </rich:column>
  </rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: I am confused. Are you using seam or not? Because the <s:selectItems> is really what you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already on JSF 2.x, then you can just use the following construct:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{answer.choices}" var="choice" itemValue="#{choice.type}" itemLabel="#{choice.value}" />
```

If you're still on JSF 1.x, then best is to use `f:selectItems` in combination with the following logic in the constructor of `answer` bean to prepopulate it:

```
this.selectItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
for (Choice choice : this.choices) {
    selectItems.add(new SelectItem(choice.getType(), choice.getValue()));
}
```

so that you can end up with

```
<f:selectItems value="#{answer.selectItems}" />
```

Comment: We are still on JSF 1.x (RichFaces 3.3.2.SR1) and don't have plans to move to JSF 2.x as of now. Will try your suggestion shortly

Comment: Have a moment, I now see that you tagged Seam as well. You should take a look for Seam's `s:selectItems` as well, it provides similar construct as the JSF 2.x `f:selectItems`.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, i tried the following.

I have the "correct" variable in my "answerList" bean in that I tried to store the selected value, but the radio button always returns a null value.

private String correct;

<h:selectOneRadio value="#{answerList.correct}">
 <f:selectItems value="#{answer.selectItems}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>

Also while inspecting using FireBug element radio button labels and values are found to be correct.

Not sure, what I am missing here

Comment: What does `h:message` or `h:messages` say? `Value not valid`? If so, you need to preserve the very same list on the subsequent request. Thus, prepopulate it in bean constructor or `@PostConstruct`. Or abuse the session scope.